# event listening jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

in a page being iframed in I have this code

```
window.parent.trigger('swipeForward');
```

now i need to listen to this event in the parent

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

 //how do i listen here for the swipeForward event

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you would any other event:

```
$(window).on('swipeForward', function () {
    // code goes here...
});
```

Don't forget to wrap `window.parent` in jQuery:

```
$(window.parent).trigger('swipeForward');
```

Comment: but i cant use window.parent.trigger('swipeForward'); ??

Comment: @Dan - You have to do `$(window.parent).trigger('swipeForward')`.

Answer (score 0):

working code

---

```
jQuery(function() {          

 if (window!=window.top) { 
 parent.window.jQuery(window.parent).trigger('swipeForward');
 }
});
```

---

code in parent page

```
jQuery(window).on('swipeForward', function () {

alert("swiped");
});
```